# unable to download phonegap from github

Tags: github, cordova

firstly I don't know where should I ask this question

I tried downloading phonegap version 2.4.0 from http://phonegap.com/install/ which links to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.4.0.zip but it will fail every single time. It will download a few mb, and it will return network error. Tried downloading it using chrome and firefox but fail. I even tried using download manager in firefox (orbit), but it will still fail with the same message, network error.

I can download files from every other place in the internet, files that are much larger than this phonegap file. I even asked my friend to try and download this file for me from another location (but in the same country, malaysia), but he will receive the same error. So do anyone else faced this problem? Or is it just a country specific problem? I have tried to download this file for the past 3 days and failed. Previously (about a month ago) I have no problem downloading this phonegap library.

Can anyone shed light to me why is this happening?

*I need the phonegap 2.4.0 since the latest version have some prob.. I read in many threads that the problem will go away with phonegap 2.4.

Comment: The link that you have posted works for me (from Australia). Perhaps there is a network issue between you and the provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded the zip and re-uploaded to my server. I have made it available for you to download here:

http://www.ronalddiaz.net/phonegap-2.4.0.zip

Hopefully you can download it from here. I will leave this link active until you download it.
Please let me know when you have downloaded it and I will delete the file from my server.

Good luck with phonegap! :)